# Drawing a custom UINavigationBar. Why this code doesn't work in retina display?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

self.tintColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:80.0f/255.0f green:150.0f/255.0f blue:185.0f/255.0f alpha:1];


[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cabecera.png"] drawInRect:rect];

}
```

I write this code in the file "CustomNavigation.m" to change the tint color and the background of a UINavigation bar. It works great in non retina IOS devices also in the retina emulator, but in an iPhone 4 with iOS 5 the code doesn't work. Someone knows why? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? That you can't see the image or that the image doesn't have the right resolution?

Comment: The image only appears in non retina devices: http://postimage.org/image/v6hp11q6x/ but I have two images, one named "cabecera.png" and other named "cabecera@2x.png", the last one prepared for retina devices.

Comment: I can tell you, that as of ios 5.0 there's a direct way of setting the background image of a UINavigationbar. Dunno, if that collides with your code though. I've had my troubles with Navigationbars and the new ios.... had to make workarounds...

Comment: But I only want to build the app for 3.2 devices... The IOS5 devices haven't backward compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the retina and non-retina devices are on different iOS versions. Also, I am assuming you are using a category to override `drawRect:` on `UINavigationBar`. This is no longer supported as of iOS 5, you must subclass `UINavigationBar` and override `drawRect:` or use the new customisation methods in iOS5 described [here](http://17.254.2.129/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html)

From the [iOS5 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_0/_index.html):

> In iOS 5, the UINavigationBar, UIToolbar, and UITabBar implementations
>   have changed so that the drawRect: method is not called unless it is
>   implemented in a subclass. Apps that have re-implemented drawRect: in
>   a category on any of these classes will find that the drawRect: method
>   isn't called. UIKit does link-checking to keep the method from being
>   called in apps linked before iOS 5 but does not support this design on
>   iOS 5 or later. Apps can either:
>
> ```
> Use the customization API for bars in iOS 5 and later, which is the preferred way.
>
> Subclass UINavigationBar (or the other bar classes) and override drawRect: in the subclass.
> ```